# In asp.net, can we identify controls whose value was changed?

Tags: asp.net

I am not asking for a particular control's change like a textbox text change event. 
But in a given aspx page, if there are multiple controls like textboxes, checkboxes etc.. can we identify what controls got changed and use their modified value?

Appreciate any pointers for this? Thanks

Comment: too broad of a question. First of all, is this MVC or webforms?

Comment: If this is ASP.NET WebForms I do not think you have a straight forward way of doing this. If you want to do it on client side you can use javascript to track events on the respective controls and send the values to server only if its changed.Or you can do it on the server side, you can create your custom controls that inherit from webcontols like TextBox etc, and then you can add additional properties like "CurrentValue" to these controls and then add function like CheckIFModified() which will check if the CurrentValue is changed. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Pharoah.
Danidev - i was referring to webforms.